# Matplotlib set individual tick style

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Simple and straightforward question. Say I have set the following X ticks with

```
plt.xticks([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Is it possible to set the tick at x = -5 to be green, the tick at x = 0 to have a different line (solid for example "-") style and the tick at x = 5 to be blue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all the tick parameters can be modified, only some of them can be. See: [document](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

However, you can change the color:

```
plt.plot(np.linspace(-10, 10), np.linspace(-10, 10))
plt.gca().tick_params('x', length=20, width=2, which='major')

xTicks = plt.xticks([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])

xTicks_cld = xTicks[0][0].get_children()
xTicks[0][0].get_children()[0].set_color('g') 
#change the color of the 1st bottom tick

xTicks[0][0].get_children()[1].set_color('r') 
#change the color of the 1st top tick

xTicks[0][-1].get_children()[0].set_color('b') 
#change the color of the last bottom tick

xTicks[0][5]._apply_params(color='r') 
#change the color of the ticks of x=0, both top and bottom xaxis.
```

[image]

Comment: Today (2023), the `tick.get_children()[i].set_color("")`-method does not work anymore.
The `tick._apply_params(color="")` method still does :)