# Change length of one (or however many) ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I'd like to change the tick length (tick beyond the plot frame) for an arbitrary tick.

I can set the visibility of just one tick (for example the second one) with

```
ax.xaxis.majorTicks[1].set_visible(False)
```

So intuitively, I tried the following to no avail:

```
ax1.xaxis.majorTicks[1].set_length(20)
```

I looked through the axes object and tried some other things, for example setting one to the color blue with the following code, again to no avail:

```
ax1.xaxis.majorTicks[1]._color = 'blue'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe try `xticklines`... it supposedly returns a list of `Line2D` instances. Not sure if they're "deep" references, though. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695057/matplotlib-set-individual-tick-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tick is a marker of a `Line2D`. The line is accessed as `tick1line` (or `tick2line` in case of the opposite axis).

```
ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[3].tick1line.set_color("red")
ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[3].tick1line.set_markersize(8)
ax1.xaxis.get_major_ticks()[3].tick1line.set_markeredgewidth(3)
```

[image]